# how to use protobuf parse big data?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, caffe

when I use caffe to read `vgg_face.caffemodel` (a 553 Mb file) in vs2010, it alert:

> ```
> Unhandled exception at 0x7644c54f in CaffeClassifierd.exe: 
> Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0035dc00
> ```

I find it's cause by `google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromCodedStream(io::CodedInputStream* input);`

Is there any way to read big data by using protobuf?

Comment: This did not solve my problem.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I  change the values of kDefaultTotalBytesLimit and kDefaultTotalBytesWarningThreshold to  64 << 32  In the file coded_stream.h of the protobuf library source, recompile, and reinstall .before use ParseFromCodedStream, I do SetTotalBytesLimit(kProtoReadBytesLimit, kProtoReadBytesLimit); this doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work": do you get the same error?

Comment: the error is still the same describe in my question.